# Как с помощью регулярного выражения удалить повторяющиеся слова?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.

Подскажите как с помощью регулярного выражения удалить повторяющиеся слова в строке. 
К примеру есть строка:

```
String st = "hello world world world world"
```

Нужно с помощью регулярного выражения удалить повторения и получить

```
String st = "hello world"
```

Нужно именно через регулярное выражение(Через разбиение строки на массив я знаю как это сделать), вообще не могу найти решение и зацепится

Comment: Собеседование чтоли? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147270/regex-in-java-for-finding-duplicate-consecutive-words

Comment: @Анатолий, надо удалить только те повторяющиеся слова, которые следуют друг за другом через пробел(ы) или оставить первые вхождения слов, повторяющихся где угодно в строке?

Comment: @Анатлий, что-нибудь помогло?

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы удалить повторяющиеся слова, разделённые пробелом (или пробелами), можно использовать следующее решение на основе регулярного выражения:

```
String str = "hello   hello world world world world";
String pat = "\\b(\\w+)(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+";
String res = str.replaceAll(pat, "$1");
System.out.println(res); // => hello world
```

[См. демо онлайн](http://ideone.com/tD0x7g)

Для регистронезависимого поиска добавьте `(?i)` в начале шаблона:

```
String pat = "(?i)\\b(\\w+)(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+";
```

**Подробности**:

- `\\b` - начало слова
- `(\\w+)` - 1+ букв, цифр или _
- `(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+` - 1 и более последовательностей:

  - `\\s+` - 1+ пробелов
  - `\\1` - обратная ссылка на значение подмаски №1
  - `\\b` - конец слова

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
String result = Arrays
            .stream(st.split("\\s+"))
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Или же, более громоздкий вариант:

```
Set<String> tokens = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (String token : st.split("\\s+"))
     if (!tokens.contains(token))
         tokens.add(token);

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (String token : tokens)
     result.append(token).append(" ");

System.out.println(result.toString());
```