# Удалить повторяющиеся слова из текста с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Есть, скажем, такая строка:

```
string = 'Word Word Word something else Word'
```

Как с помощью регулярных выражений, данную строку привести к виду:

```
string = 'Word something else Word'
```

т.е слова повторяющиеся единожды не изменять, а те слова которые встречаются последовательно несколько раз, удалить и оставить только одно из ряда повторяющихся.

Comment: покажите ваш вариант решения

Comment: Вопросов про работу с повторами масса и они даже с готовыми ответами ... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: А если будет `string = 'Word,Word; Word something else Word'`? Тут есть много частных случаев.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как с помощью регулярного выражения удалить повторяющиеся слова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652427/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно оттолкнуться от этого

```
string = 'Word Word Word something else Word'
r = %r{(?<word>\w+) +(?=\k<word>)}

puts string.gsub(r, '')
```

здесь `?<word>` - именованная группа,
а `?=` просмотр вперед с возвратом

Comment: А если мне нужно исключать не все дублирующиеся слова в строке, а конкретное слово ( word или любое другое), а остальные дублирующиеся слова не трогать, как быть? то есть строка: string = 'Word Word Word something else else Word', а на выходе получить: string = 'Word something else else Word',

Comment: просто заметь поиск слов из любых букв на конкретное слово: `r = %r{(?<word>(Word)) +(?=\k<word>)}`

Comment: Благодарю Вас!
Очень выручили