# Удалить повторяющиеся слова в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения, oracle

Необходимо удалить повторяющееся слово, если оно идет друг за другом, в строке (разделитель пробел или не текстовый символ).
Пытаюсь сделать шаблон регулярной функции в Oracle.

Нашёл данный формат шаблона, но не могу его перенести в regexp_replace на Oracle:
`\\b(\\w+)(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+`

[Как с помощью регулярного выражения удалить повторяющиеся слова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652427/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Спасибо @ESkri за пример, немного модернизировал для своих нужд:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('ООО ДО-ДО ПИЦЦА',
                      '(^|\W)(\w{2,})(\s+\2)+(\W|$)',
                      '\1\2\4',
                      1,
                      0,
                      'i')
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оракл не поддерживает полностью все фичи перловских регвыров, в частности, `\b`.

```
select
    regexp_replace(
        'Ха-ха-ха, он чуть-чуть не увёз мою чау-чау в Баден-Баден',
        '(^|\W)(\w+)(\W+\2)+(\W|$)',
        '\1\2\4',
        1, 0, 'i')
from dual
```

Результат:

```
Ха, он чуть не увёз мою чау в Баден
```